# Javascript Class: getter value when instantiating the class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a quick question - it was challenge in Hacker Rank - trying  to find an answer.

Question goes like this.

Console log should print the reverse order of numbers in the class.
Restrictions:
1. Class constructor should not be modified.
2. Console log statement should not be modified.

You can do anything else to make it working.

```
class HeyNumber {
  get numbers() {
    return [2, 1, 2, 3];
  }

  // You should not change the constructor
  constructor() {
    return this;
  }
}

// You should not alter the following line 
console.log(Array.from(new HeyNumber()).join(',')) // 3,2,1,2
```

Just curious to know how we can implement this?

Comment: See the specification for the operations `Array.prototype.from` performs - is there anything useful in that? Since ES6, these steps are painfully explicitly specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using symbol iterator is one of many ways

```js
class HeyNumber {
  get numbers() {
    return [2, 1, 2, 3];
  }
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this.numbers.reverse().values()
  }
  // You should not change the constructor
  constructor() {
    return this;
  }
}

// You should not alter the following line 
console.log(Array.from(new HeyNumber()).join(',')) // 3,2,1,2
```

Comment: If i would put more effort into it then i would have used for loop to yeild values backwards

Comment: Nice one.. did not think about that solution would be coming..

Comment: One of many? There's only two ways how `Array.from` arrives at an array afaik, and the non-iterator one would not be very comfortable.

Comment: @bergi you can patch `array.from`, `Array,prototype.join`, wrap the class in a closure and create another class with the same name that extends the HeyNumber. You can also use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: @Endless Ah, but that's cheating :D

Comment: nah... it was not one of the Restrictions :P

Comment: then, depending on how you interpret #2 you could also patch console log, you are not changing the source/statement. just changing the behavior

Answer (score 0):

Okey here is another class extending one:

```js
class HeyNumber extends (class HeyNumber {
  get numbers() {
    return [2, 1, 2, 3];
  }
  
  // You should not change the constructor
  constructor() {
    return this;
  }
}) {
  constructor() {
    return super().numbers.reverse()
  } 
}

// You should not alter the following line 
console.log(Array.from(new HeyNumber()).join(',')) // 3,2,1,2
```

Is this cheating? I have not touched the class at all, I'm still printing the reverse order of numbers in the class you provided :P

Answer (score 0):

```js
class HeyNumber {
  get numbers() {
    return [2, 1, 2, 3];
  }

  // You should not change the constructor
  constructor() {
    return this;
  }
}

// jank
new HeyNumber().numbers.reverse().forEach((v, i, a) => {
  HeyNumber.prototype[i] = v
  HeyNumber.prototype.length = a.length
})

// You should not alter the following line 
console.log(Array.from(new HeyNumber()).join(',')) // 3,2,1,2
```

Comment: there are Endless solutions

Answer (score -2):

First, it looks like you **should** alter the final line to fix a bug:

```
console.log(Array.from(new HeyNumber()).join(',')) // ''
console.log(Array.from(new HeyNumber().numbers).join(',')) // 2,1,2,3
```

Then, try the following on Line 3:

```
return [2, 1, 2, 3].reverse();
```

Comment: It specifically says in restrictions. you should not alter the console.log line or the constructor. @simon

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.